# Memory capacity for 'range optimizer max mem_size' exceeded

Tags: python, mysql, sql, python-3.x

I'm connecting to MySQL with Python like this:

```
    db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", user="****", passwd="****", db="****", charset='utf8')
    db.query(sql)
    result = db.use_result()
    event_data = result.fetch_row(maxrows=1, how=1)
    if event_data:
         event_data=event_data[0]
```

So i'm not fetching all the result at one time, but i'm fetching row by row, it uses less memory and works faster.
Usually it works fine, but I got a strange error:

> 3170, "Memory capacity of 8388608 bytes for 'range optimizer max
>   mem_size' exceeded. Range optimization was not done for this query.

It is strange because the result is around 500 000 rows with is not the biggest one, plus I'm processing in row by row without fetching it into RAM and I never got this error before.

I have a big 'ID in (*ID's LIST)' expression inside, but if the query is too long I'm getting an OperationalError, witch I handle with several chunks of ID's and there was never a problem.

Comment: Did you set the "fetch size" to a value other than the default? Maybe it's trying to load all the rows at once.

Comment: @TheImpaler no, is has maxrows=1

Answer (score 3):

SET GLOBAL range_optimizer_max_mem_size=0;

0 for unlimited memory
you can also give limit here in bytes like 8388608